# What is the minimal configuration to activate timbre and redirect all timbre logging to slf4j?

Tags: logging, clojure, timbre

I use SLF4J and Logback in my projects, and typically do all my logging using [tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging). Every time I have to use a library that uses timbre, I have never been able to get the right code added to my project to see anything logged.

**What is the minimum configuration I need in my project to make sure that timbre logging is active and make timbre redirect all logging to tools.logging (so that the timbre logging will appear in my logs)?**

1. I've tried adding the following to my main namespace:

   ```
   (timbre/merge-config!
    {:level :info
     :appenders {:tools-logging (com.palletops.log-config.timbre.tools-logging/make-tools-logging-appender {})}})
   ```

   This attempts to use the [timbre->tools.logging bridge](https://github.com/palletops/log-config#logging-from-timbre-to-java-logging) from the https://github.com/palletops/log-config project.

   But I never see any logging.
2. If I take out the `:appenders` section above, I get nothing logged to the console (shouldn't timbre log to the console by default?).
3. If I use the following, I still see nothing:

   ```
   (timbre/merge-config!
    {:level :info
     :appenders {:standard-out {:enabled? true}}})
   ```

   even though I know that the library I'm using is make multiple calls to `taoensso.timbre/error`

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the latest version of Timbre, but [I have a demo here](https://github.com/cloojure/demo-timbre):

```
~/expr/demo-timbre > 
~/expr/demo-timbre > lein run
Hello, World!
~/expr/demo-timbre > cat log.txt 
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy DEBUG [log-timbre.core] - Hello, Timbre! debug
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Hello, Timbre! info
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy WARN [log-timbre.core] - Hello, Timbre! warn
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy ERROR [log-timbre.core] - Hello, Timbre! error
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy FATAL [log-timbre.core] - Hello, Timbre! fatal
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Arg-1
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Arg-1 :Arg-2
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Arg-1 :Arg-2 [Arg-3]
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Arg-1 :Arg-2 [Arg-3] {:Arg 4}
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Spy returns the last value {:a 1}
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy DEBUG [log-timbre.core] - (* 6 7) 42
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy WARN [log-timbre.core] - (* 6 7) 42
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy ERROR [log-timbre.core] - optional message {:a 1}
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy ERROR [log-timbre.core] - Any extra :items {:go here}
java.lang.Exception: Doh!
         log-timbre.core/-main                          core.clj:   58
       clojure.lang.Var.invoke                          Var.java:  375
                    user/eval5  form-init4075346110151967627.clj:    1
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval                     Compiler.java: 6768
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval                     Compiler.java: 6758
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load                     Compiler.java: 7195
clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile                     Compiler.java: 7151
      clojure.main/load-script                          main.clj:  274
         clojure.main/init-opt                          main.clj:  279
       clojure.main/initialize                          main.clj:  307
         clojure.main/null-opt                          main.clj:  342
             clojure.main/main                          main.clj:  420
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke                       RestFn.java:  421
       clojure.lang.Var.invoke                          Var.java:  383
clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper                          AFn.java:  156
      clojure.lang.Var.applyTo                          Var.java:  700
             clojure.main.main                         main.java:   37

2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - (my-fn) =>  42
2018-Sep-28 13:02:12 -0700 brandy INFO [log-timbre.core] - Profiling: :log-timbre.core/Arithmetic
                         Id      nCalls       Min        Max       MAD      Mean   Time% Time
:log-timbre.core/slow-sleep         100     2.0ms      2.0ms    13.0μs     2.0ms      60 208.0ms
:log-timbre.core/fast-sleep         100     1.0ms      1.0ms     8.0μs     1.0ms      31 108.0ms
       :log-timbre.core/div         100    36.0μs    214.0μs    16.0μs    51.0μs       1 5.0ms
      :log-timbre.core/mult         100    22.0μs    197.0μs    13.0μs    34.0μs       1 3.0ms
       :log-timbre.core/add         100    16.0μs    345.0μs    16.0μs    32.0μs       1 3.0ms
       :log-timbre.core/sub         100    16.0μs    198.0μs    13.0μs    28.0μs       1 3.0ms
                 Clock Time                                                          100 345.0ms
             Accounted Time                                                           96 331.0ms
```